# Is Bernoulli's equation (with major and minor energy loss) valid for viscid flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I read that the Bernoulli's equation cannot be applied to viscid flow. 
But when calculating friction head loss, we find Darcy friction factor f, for which we need to calculate Reynold's number which has a viscosity term.

Comment: So, you are using the modified version of the Bernoulli equation that includes these head losses.  That is valid.